# How to acess node object in hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I am trying to access the node object in `hook_form_alter()`, but it throws the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: #node in `themename_form_alter()`

The code I am using is the following.

```
function themename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)) {
  $node = $form['#node'];
}
```

Is there any way to access the node object in `hook_form_alter()`?

Answer (score 8):

Not all the forms contains a reference to a node. It is just some node forms which contain a node object, but `hook_form_alter()` is called for every form being output from Drupal.

What you need to do is the following:

- Check `$form['#node']` is set

  ```
  if (isset($form['#node'])) {
    // …
  }
  ```
- Use a different hook, such as `hook_form_node_form_alter()` if you want to alter the node edit form for any content type, or `hook_form_$type_node_form_alter()` for the node edit form of the `$type` content type

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will try with hooks you suggested.